# Using Google Authenticator with Chrome Plugins

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome plugin which allows the users to email any web content from a html page. For that, I need to use the google authenticator api to allow users to log into their google accounts for sending emails. The OAuth2.0 specs require the redirect_ui parameter which is the url to be called after google authenticates the user. My question is whether it is possible to skip this parameter. I don't want the plugin to be hosted anywhere. I am thinking that it would be hosted locally on the user's machine.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has made a library specifically for using OAuth in Chrome extensions. You can check out the tutorial [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_oauth.html).

Answer (score 0):

In case someone stumbles upon this answer in 2017+, extensions (in Chrome and FF) now have a [`chrome.identity` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity).

It takes care of the OAuth dance for you, and provides you with a *virtual* redirect address `https://<your-extension-id>.chromiumapp.org/` that will be intercepted by the browser. That way, you can provide a redirect URL without hosting anything.